# how to consume web service from desktop c# app?

Tags: web-services, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to consume a HTTP web service returning XML generated by a DataContractSerializer in a C# Desktop application. The link to the service doesn't have any aspx or svc extention, and the parameters are expected in the link.

https://sourcesite.com/api/external/v1/Snapshot?isConfirmed={isConfirmed}&sinceDate={sinceDate}&pageNumber={pageNumber}&recordsPerPage={recordsPerPage}

It works when I use it in a browser (after providing proper parameter values). When run for the first time it asked me my credentials which it accepted and didn't ask again, even after the browser restart.

I tried adding a web reference (using VS2013), using url without the parameters  but I'm getting errors:

`The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.`

If I add hardcoded parameters, I get:

`The document at the url https://sourcesite.com/api/external/v1/Snapshot?isConfirmed=True was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.'.
- Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (1, 1).'.
  - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://sourcesite.com/api/external/v1/Snapshot?isConfirmed=True'.
The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed.
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.`

Is the service incorrectly configured, or am I missing something? Perhaps there's a different way to connect to this service form the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Add Service Reference" and "Add Web Reference" are for SOAP web services.

You'll have to use the `WebClient` class and "do it yourself".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll direct my research towards it.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work:

```
        var netCred = new NetworkCredential { UserName = "user1", Password = @"pass1" };
        WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
        proxy.Credentials = netCred;

        //Method 1 - Newtonsoft.Json


            string serviceURL =
               string.Format("https://sourcesite.com.com/api/external/v1/Snapshot-Accrual?isConfirmed="
                + Confirmed.ToString() + "&sinceDate=" + String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", SinceDate);
            data = proxy.DownloadData(serviceURL);
            jsonString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data);

            ac1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SnapshotAccruals>(jsonString);
```

Now if I only knew how to prompt for credentials instead of hard-coding them, I'd be set. I know that if I paste the serviceURL directly in the browser, it will ask me for credentials. If I omit them in the code I get (401) Unauthorized.